# Applying a "Spread" value to an XMFLOAT4X4

Tags: rotation, directx-11, matrix-multiplication, quaternions

I'm attempting to add a small value to a World Matrix in order to replicate the accuracy of a fired weapon [pistol, assault rifle]

Currently, my World Matrix resides at a Parent Objects' position, with the ability to rotate about the Y axis exclusively.

I've done this in Unity3D, running whenever the object needs to be created [once per]:

```
        var coneRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Random.Range(-spread, spread), Random.Range(-spread, spread), 0);
        var go = Instantiate(obj, parent.transform.position, transform.rotation * coneRotation) as GameObject;
```

and am attempting to replicate the results using Direct3D11.

This lambda returns a random value between [-1.5, 1.5] currently:

```
    auto randF = [&](float lower_bound, float uppder_bound) -> float
    {
        return lower_bound + static_cast <float> (rand()) / (static_cast <float> (RAND_MAX / (uppder_bound - lower_bound)));
    };
```

My first thought was to simply multiply a random `x` && `y` into the `forward` vector of an object upon initialization, and move it in this fashion: `position = position + forward * speed * dt;` [`speed` being `1800`], though the rotation is incorrect (not to mention bullets fire up).

I've also attempted to make a Quaternion [as in Unity3D]: `XMVECTOR quaternion = XMVectorSet(random_x, random_y, 0)` and creating a Rotation Matrix using `XMMatrixRotationQuaternion`.

Afterwards I call `XMStoreFloat4x4(&world_matrix, XMLoadFloat4x4(&world_matrix) * rotation);`, and restore the position portion of the matrix [accessing world_matrix._41/._42/._43] (world_matrix being the matrix of the "bullet" itself, not the parent).

[I've also tried to reverse the order of the multiplication]

I've read that the `XMMatrixRotationQuaternion` doesn't return as an Euler Quaternion, and `XMQuaternionToAxisAngle` does, though I'm not entirely certain how to use it.

What would be the proper way to accomplish something like this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code `XMVECTOR quaternion = XMVectorSet(random_x, random_y, 0);` is not creating a valid quaternion. First, if you did not set the `w` component to 1, then the 4-vector quaternion doesn't actually represent a 3D rotation. Second, a quaternion's vector components are not Euler angles.

You want to use `XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw` which constructs a quaternion rotation from Euler angle input, or `XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYawFromVector` which takes the three Euler angles as a vector. These functions are doing what Unity's `Quaternion.Euler` method is doing.

Of course, if you want a rotation matrix and not a quaternion, then you can `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYaw` or `XMMatrixRotationRollPitchYawFromVector` to directly construct a 4x4 rotation matrix from Euler angles--which actually uses quaternions internally anyhow. Based on your code snippet, it looks like you already have a base rotation as a quaternion you want to concatenate with your spread quaternion, so you probably don't want to use this option for this case.

**Note:** You should look at using the C++11 standard `<random>` rather than your home-rolled lambda wrapper around the terrible C `rand` function.

Something like:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gen(rd());

// spread should be in radians here (not degrees which is what Unity uses)
std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-spread, spread);
XMVECTOR coneRotation = XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw( dis(gen), dis(gen), 0 );
XMVECTOR rot = XMQuaternionMultiply( parentRot, coneRotation );
XMMATRIX transform = XMMatrixAffineTransformation( g_XMOne, g_XMZero, rot, parentPos );
```

BTW, if you are used to Unity or XNA Game Studio C# math libraries, you might want to check out the [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) wrapper for DirectXMath in [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).

Comment: I actually didn't notice the `w` component of the `Quaternion` [which i believe to be the scale] wasn't set to `1`. If I wanted to duplicate the `Quaternion.Euler` method contained in Unity3D, what would be required? [I'm trying to port my Unity3D game to Direct3D11, as directly as I can]

Comment: ``Quaternion.Euler`` for Unity: "Returns a rotation that rotates z degrees around the z axis, x degrees around the x axis, and y degrees around the y axis (in that order).".  ``XMQuaternionRotationRollPitchYaw``  computes the roll (Z-axis), pitch (X-axis), and then yaw (Y-axis rotation) given radians.